# Can't get dup2 to redirect output for my own commands but works for execvp

Tags: c++, operating-system, pipe, execvp

Currently, I'm trying to redirect the output of my function to pie but it doesn't seem to work. All it does is just print to the screen the pwd and doesn't do anything to pie.txt. Trying to implement `pwd > pie`. Thanks in advance! I'm copying the example `redirect.c` from this website http://www.cs.loyola.edu/~jglenn/702/S2005/Examples/dup2.html. If I copy it exactly, it works. But when I try it with my own command it doesn't work.

```
 void printWord(std::string cmd) {
    char c[cmd.size() + 1];
    std::copy(cmd.begin(), cmd.end(), c);
    c[cmd.size()] = '\0';
    write(STDIN_FILENO, &c, strlen(c));
}
void printPWD() {
    std::vector<char> buffer;
    std::string dir = getcwd(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
    printWord("\n" + dir + "\n");
}
int main () {
  int in, out;
  char *grep_args[] = { "grep", "cpp", NULL };

  // open input and output files

  out =
    open ("pie.txt", O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT,
      S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IWUSR);

  dup2 (out, 1);
  close (out);

  printPWD(); 
  return 0;
}
```

Trying to get `pwd > pie` to work.

Comment: Start by constructing a (much) simpler program -- only what you need for testing a simple redirection.  Your `main()`, taken by itself, is pretty close to that -- changing the `execCommand()` calls to appropriate `execvp()` calls might be enough.  Test the basics of setting up a pipe with that (and post that as your [mre] if you have questions for us about it) before you build somethign more elaborate on top.

Comment: My problem is that it does work when I use 'execvp()' when I redirect and pipe. However, once I use the function I implemented, it doesn't work. I have to use my own functions for (ls,pwd, and ff) and then I use 'execvp()' for the other commands like grep, echo, wc, etc. How can I post a minimal reproducible example without showing my function that is the problem?

Comment: I have made it much simpler! Any help in would be appreciated.

Comment: You could start by clarifying in the question what you just wrote about the redirection working for you if you `execvp()` directly, and especially showing the code that worked for you, possibly in commented-out form in the listing.  You could continue by dropping the unneeded cases from `execCommand()`, and dropping the extra functions that then will not be used.

Comment: The program now presented in the question is writing to `STDIN_FILENO`, which produces undefined behavior.  If I change that to `STDOUT_FILENO` then the output goes to file `pie.txt`.

Comment: Oh my god. You are my hero. I have been working on this problem for 2 days. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome.  Please do not take offense that I am about to vote to close the question as off topic on account of being caused by a typographical error.